# How to donate gold in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I play with friends but I also play more than them and consequently I have better stuff and more gold.

Since I'm the friendly kind of guy, I want to *donate* gold to my friends so they can buy better stuff in the Action House and we can play together again with our most advanced character. Right now, I need to play with my second or third best character to match their advancement...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Join their game, run up to them, and right click their portait - there should be a *Trade* option, which will allow you to trade gold directly to them.

Note that this only works while you're in town.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll check tonight (EU time) and validate if that's the right answer. :)

Comment: Is this maybe only available in town?

Answer (score 2):

Trading or gifting gold is no longer possible since February 2014, see:
[How can gold be traded to other players Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162580/how-can-gold-be-traded-to-other-players-diablo-3?rq=1)

You can still power level them, invite them into your game whenever you find [the vault](http://diablowiki.net/The_Vault), or gift them items you find while playing in the same party.