# How to give money to another player?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to donate gold in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69166/how-to-donate-gold-in-diablo-3)

I never found the button to do this.

For example, I can drop a set of armor for my friends to pickup, but I cant do the same thing with money.

Could be useful when my friend is 2GP away to create a good equipement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trade with the player, and enter the amount you want to give into the gold box. Then everything will work as if you'd do a normal trade.